# How can I fix this exception I get when I try to use the FxCop introspection engine?

Tags: fxcop, introspection

I am getting an exception when I try to use the FxCop introspection engine:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Cci, Version=9.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. 
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

What does this exception mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, fixed it. FxCop assemblies are 32bit, my project was 64bit. Changed the build to x86 and the problem is fixed.